# How to dynamically set wait message to send to Active mq in mule

Tags: activemq-classic, mule-studio

Is there any way I can dynamically set a waiting value for a message to be sent to an Active mq from mule?
I have a requirement where I need to wait the message before I send to a queue in Active mq. I need to make that waiting value configuration dynamically may be from a variable.
I know I can use `sleep()` in `groovy` to ake the message hold for some time, I have seen few examples, but I don't want to use groovy or `sleep()` or any kind of hack to do this.

Is there any other way in connector level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY` header in jms component to set the delay.
You can set it it through flow variable as header.
An example you can find here that can help you https://dzone.com/articles/delay-with-jms

Here how you can set the delay in component level

```
<message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
<add-message-property key="AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY" value="#[flowVars.delay]"/>
</message-properties-transformer>
<json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
<jms:outbound-endpoint queue="testqueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
```

Now you set the flow variable before you send in the mule flow

Comment: can we set the queue value with variables?